# PHPUnit + Symfony 1.4 + Doctrine: Best practice of fixture loading

Tags: database, unit-testing, symfony1, phpunit, fixtures

I am trying to get my PHPUnit Database Tests in place for my Symfony 1.4 on Doctrine.
Unfortunately I don't know the best practice for this. Everything I try seems to have disadvantages.

What I already Tried:

1.
I let my UnitTest class inherit from PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase. Then I work with implementing the abstract methods getConnection and getDataset. I would prefer to configure my fixtures in yaml. So I wrote some files (one file per model). Loading one file or multiple independent files work, but if I have key constraints in it, I really have to take care to use the correct ids.

1. I used the standard sfPHPUnitBaseTestCase as the base class and had a

   Doctrine::loadData(sfConfig::get('sf_test_dir').'/fixtures/book.yml');
   Doctrine::loadData(sfConfig::get('sf_test_dir').'/fixtures/author.yml');

in the setUp Method. Here I could use the Doctrine way of identifiy foreign key relations by name, like

```
Author:
  Author_1:
    name: Max Mustermann

Book:
  Book_1:
    title: The first book
    Author: Author_1
```

which I really like because it is very intuitive.

But the Doctrine::loadData is only executing a "DELETE FROM " and not a truncate, which causes problems for my lookup tables, where ids are important. Solution here would be to put the ids as well in the fixtures file.

So theses are my two approaches, of which both would work but none seems really perfect for me. Do you have any ideas of a better practice.

Thanks a lot